# Calculating using entry properties in Org mode clocktable

Tags: org-mode

I have some entries in an Org mode file that have a property containing a lambda expression:

```
* Tasks
** Task 1
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Formula:     (lambda (x) (max 20.0 (* 11.0 x)))
   :END:
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2023-10-25 Wed 11:31]--[2023-10-25 Wed 13:25] =>  1:54
   :END:
** Task 2
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Formula:     (lambda (x) (* 9.5 x))
   :END:
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2023-10-10 Fri 16:40]--[2023-10-10 Fri 17:26] =>  0:46
   CLOCK: [2023-10-10 Fri 15:10]--[2023-10-10 Fri 15:22] =>  0:12
   :END:
```

I would like it if when I created a clocktable using such entries, there was a way to create some extra columns using these formulas. Namely, I'd like to interpret each formula as the way to calculate the cost associated with the task using the time as input; in other words, in the example above for Task 1 I'd like to call `(lambda (x) (max 20.0 (* 11.0 x)))` with the input `1 + 54/60`.

In the final table, I'd like an extra column for the formula, and an extra column for the result of calling the lambda. So instead of

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope file :block 2023-10
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2023-11-08 Wed 12:42], for October 2023.
| Headline                                   |   Time |      |
|--------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| *Total time*                               | *2:52* |      |
|--------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| Tasks                                      |   2:52 |      |
| \_  Task 1                                 |        | 1:54 |
| \_  Task 2                                 |        | 0:58 |
#+END:
```

the table would instead look like:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope file :block 2023-10
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2023-11-08 Wed 12:42], for October 2023.
| Headline                 |   Time |      | Formula                            | Cost  |
|--------------------------+--------+------|------------------------------------+-------|
| *Total time*             | *2:52* |      |                                    |       |
|--------------------------+--------+------|------------------------------------+-------|
| Tasks                    |   2:52 |      |                                    |       |
| \_  Task 1               |        | 1:54 | (lambda (x) (max 20.0 (* 11.0 x))) | 20.90 |
| \_  Task 2               |        | 0:58 | (lambda (x) (* 9.5 x))             |  9.18 |
#+END:
```

It would also be really nice if there was a final row containing the total cost.

I am vaguely aware of things like `TBLFM` in Org mode but can't really tell if it's capable of doing something like this. I have also seen some templates for creating invoices using Org mode, but these all just have a single rate that is being multiplied by the time, whereas I'd like to have custom formulas.